# C# Console App error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property"

Tags: c#-4.0

> Error  1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ConsoleApplication_FileTest.Program.GetAverageSalary(string)'    C:\Users\Dawn\documents\visual studio 11\Projects\ConsoleApplication_FileTest\ConsoleApplication_FileTest\Program.cs    98  24  ConsoleApplication_FileTest

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Dictionary<string, double> averages = new Dictionary<string, double>();
    string filename = "c:\\test.txt";
    averages = GetAverageSalary(filename)
}
```

=====================

```
        Dictionary<string, double> GetAverageSalary(string filename)
        {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `GetAverageSalary` is not `static`. You must change it to

```
static Dictionary<string, double> GetAverageSalary(string filename)
```